# Automate inserting 2FA code when screen is locked

Tags: screen, automation, 2fa

I use a service for which I'm forced to use two-factor authentication whenever I log in. It's pretty inconvenient and unnecessary, so I would like to automate accepting the authentication request when it arrives on my phone.

The service uses an Android app that sends a notification when an authentication request arrives. When I then open the app, I need to insert a 4-digit PIN code which accepts the request.

I tried using an automation app (MacroDroid) to open the 2FA app whenever it sends a notification and simulates the four clicks. However, this only works when the phone is unlocked, and as far as I understand, I will run into this problem with any automation app.

The goal is to accept any authentication request without having to interact with my phone. Is there a way to insert the code without unlocking my screen? Would I have to root it? Or do I just have to keep my phone permanently unlocked?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. I would go an alternate route. Install an android emulator on a pc, install the 2FA automation there, and just keep that running. Do note that bypassing 2FA is very insecure and is definitely not recommended. I would complain about it and see if you either can get extempted from the service side, or that they allow some kind of caching, such that you only have to accept it every x days.

Comment: Installing a 2FA on a desktop doesn’t require an Android emulator provided its not Okta Verify, since that particular 2FA, is special

Answer (score 0):

I have automated this by using WinAuth. Once the QR auth is fed, it supports using a shortcut key to enter Auth PIN on any text field. Very handy and I am able to login at 2FA sites/applications in a jiffy with this

Comment: Hi Arvind, its too succinct for mosr people. Prrhaps you could edit it and expand it.

Comment: Looks like this is a Windows app, not an Android app. Did you mean to supplement the suggestion in the comment thread on the question regarding "using an Android emulator on a PC"? Otherwise, could you [edit] and expand on how to achieve this with an Android device?